# Maven dependency timeout settings

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

Maven reports timeout exception while downloading dependencies, as it's default time out is 60000, but in my case I need to increase because ( The environment where I am working has established an intermediary server that first download all the file to it's own server and my machine get those downloaded file from that intermediary server).
Now here the problem comes, if the dependency is too large simply that takes more than 60000 mili seconds then eclipse burst with the following exception

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Aggregator
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension API
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension SPI
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Core
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension DBUnit Integration
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Integration Tests
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Arquillian Persistence Extension Aggregator 1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ arquillian-persistence-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ arquillian-persistence-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack (unpack) @ arquillian-persistence-parent ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.wildfly:wildfly-dist:8.0.0.Final:zip
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/wildfly-dist/8.0.0.Final/wildfly-dist-8.0.0.Final.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Aggregator ....... FAILURE [2:11.315s]
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension API .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension SPI .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Core ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension DBUnit Integration  SKIPPED
[INFO] Arquillian Persistence Extension Integration Tests  SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:11.908s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 07 11:27:41 PKT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/177M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack (unpack) on project arquillian-persistence-parent: Unable to resolve artifa
ct. Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly:wildfly-dist:zip:8.0.0.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
[ERROR] org.wildfly:wildfly-dist:zip:8.0.0.Final
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

No response received after 60000 , this line creates trouble.

**As a Solution :**

I am using **settings.xml** with the following settings

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>central</id>
      <configuration>
            <timeout>120000</timeout>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

while I am sure the path of the settings.xml is correct.

Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: I've found http://brettporter.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/configuring-maven-http-connections/ that describes exactly what you did, but I'm not able to make it work either.

Comment: Hi @rajper, would you consider to accept my answer or adding a comment about why it didn't work out ?

Comment: Hi @Max, would you please consider accepting my answer if it fixes your problem ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [this Maven guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html) there's a new way to set up timeouts.
I changed my `~/settings.xml` that now reads like that...

```
<server>
  <id>central</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpConfiguration>
      <all>
        <connectionTimeout>120000</connectionTimeout>
        <readTimeout>120000</readTimeout>
      </all>
    </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

It seems to work in my case. I tried with an unexisting repository and it seems to fail far quicker than before, when I set both timeouts to 5000. Can you give it a try ?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I added a server entry for each repository and pluginRepository "id" that I wanted timeouts for.  For example, when I develop from home, maven can't resolve our intranet maven repo and was hanging for ages. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For Maven 3.9.0+ or newer, you can use the following, as described in the [Guide for Resolver Transport](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html):

```
<server>
  <id>central</id>
  <configuration>
    <connectTimeout>120000</connectTimeout>
    <requestTimeout>120000</requestTimeout>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

The original answer references [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html), which now indicates:

> This page contains Wagon specific information, but **the default transport in Maven 3.9.0+ is NOT Wagon anymore**. Make sure to check Resolver Transport guide first, as things have changed.