# Hibernate spatial is offline - anyone got more information

Tags: offline, hibernate-spatial

Since a few days [hibernatespatial.org](http://www.hibernatespatial.org) is offline, along with the mailing lists and Maven repositories. Has anyone got news on that?

Comment: server may go offline maybe because of electricity failure or web site maintainance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's online now, and pointing interested parties at Hibernate's own site since the project is being brought into the Hibernate fold.

Comment: And offline again :-( Thanks for the info regarding the transition, Duncan!

Comment: Hey Duncan. It's currently not reponding again. Is there a static copy of the http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository somewhere? We are using it in daily maven builds...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue (hibernatespatial.org has been offline for days). I was able to resolve it by uploading the artifacts to our internal repo and then setting hibernate to timeout almost immediately [Maven dependency timeout settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510525/maven-dependency-timeout-settings).

The ideal solution would be to upgrade to a 5.0.x version that is on maven central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial.