# Is the Maven repository for hibernatespatial version 4 down?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spatial, hibernate-spatial

I'm working on a project using hibernate and hibernate spatial version 4.0.

In my pom files I have setup the repository like this:

```
<repository>
  <id>Hibernate spatial repo</id>
  <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
</repository>
```

and the dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
  <version>4.0-M1</verison>
</dependency>
```

This setting worked well till begin of July. Now the build process tries to contact hibernatespatial.org for all packages for download, but gets only timeout warnings.

I've noticed, that the new version 5.x has been migrated to hibernate.org. Are there any changes regarding the old repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [this](https://twitter.com/andimabxl/status/755729477511024640) tweets exchange. [here](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2016-April/014721.html) sounds like they had no clear idea how to proceed with that site. Version 5 has been integrated into Hibernate core [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6509) hence also available via maven central indeed.

Comment: See additional info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443434/hibernate-spatial-is-offline-anyone-got-more-information/40725418#40725418

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Spatial has been merged into Hibernate ORM 5.0. The `hibernatespatial.org` site will be discontinued, along with the Maven Repository.

Hibernate Spatial 5.0 is just a module in Hibernate ORM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And the Hibernate User Guide contains a [chapter about Spatial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial) as well.

The `hibernatespatial.org` is owned and controlled by Hibernate Spatial creator, so if he decided to discontinue the site, there's nothing we can do about it.

Since Hibernate Spatial 4.0 is not avilable on Maven Central, so you should probably upgrade to Hibernate 5.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, the whole site http://www.hibernatespatial.org seems to be down.

After a quick search on twitter & google I got the impression they go offline every now and then. A colleague of mine told me last time this happened was in May 2016 and the site was down for about two days. (Today is day #2 that I'm waiting for them to come back and I know for sure that both the repo and the site hibernatespatial.org were online last week).

Also I found out the hibernate-spatial is on maven central from version 5 onwards.

The versions 4.0 and 4.3 can be found on this repo: http://nexus.e-is.pro/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-spatial/