# How to optimize mvn dependency download

Tags: java, maven

1. Why does mvn wait for other calls when it is already done with the download

Based on the logs below, maven tries to download from other repositories though on line 5 it says "Downloaded". Looks like mvn did not find any updates on this resource, I guess that is why it reports "(0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)". I am not sure. Original subdomain is concealed here and shown as 'xyz' or 'abc', they are actually valid subdomains on intranet.

```
Downloading: http://xyz.qa.ebay.com/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom     
Downloading: http://xyz.qa.ebay.com/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom     
Downloading: http://abc.qa.ebay.com/nexus/content/repositories/testinfrastructure.releases/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloading: http://xyz/content/repositories/central/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloaded: http://xyz/content/repositories/central/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
Downloading: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.pom
```

2. Timeout configuration applied on <server> is not getting picked up. [Stack overflow related issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510525/maven-dependency-timeout-settings)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
<servers>
<server>
  <id>my-server</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpConfiguration>
      <all>
        <connectionTimeout>5000</connectionTimeout> <!-- milliseconds -->
        <readTimeout>20000</readTimeout>
      </all>
    </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
</server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/central</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>xyz</id>
        <properties>
            <archetypeCatalog>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/releases/archetype-catalog.xml
            </archetypeCatalog>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>framework.releases</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral.qa.xyz.com/content/repositories/releases/
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>framework.snapshots</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral.qa.xyz.com/content/repositories/snapshots/
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>framework-thirdparty</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral.qa.xyz.com/content/repositories/thirdparty/
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>repo1.releases</id>
                <url>http://abccentral.qa.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/repo1.releases/
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>repo1.snapshots</id>
                <url>http://abccentral.qa.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/repo1.snapshots/
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>framework-releases</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/releases</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>framework-plugins</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/plugins</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>framework-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>framework-thirdparty</id>
                <url>http://xyzcentral/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>xyz</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: The simplest solution for such problems is to use a repository manager which simplifies the configuration...

Comment: Can't the above issue solved using server configuration ? sonatype nexus is used in our company

Comment: If it is already used so you should use it correctly. And the above settings.xml file looks wrong.Read the documentation of Nexus in deep and configure based on the suggestions made in the docs.